# Slow regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match these kinds of strings

```
{@csm.foo.bar}
```

without matching any of these

```
{@csm.foo.bar-@csm.ooga.booga}
{@csm.foo.bar-42}
```

The regex I use is

```
r"\{@csm.((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.?)+)\}"
```

It gets dog slow if the string contains multiple matches. Why? It runs very fast if I take away the brace matching, like this

```
r"@csm.((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.?)+)"
```

but that's not what I want.

Any ideas?

Here is sample input:

```
<dockLayout id="popup" y="0" x="0" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.screenHeight}">
  <dataNumber id="selopacity_Volt" name="selopacity_Volt" value="0" />
  <dataNumber id="selopacity_Amp" name="selopacity_Amp" value="0" />
  <animate  trigger="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryVoltage.valstr}" triggerOn="*"  targetNode="selopacity_Volt"  targetAttr="value" to="1" dur="0ms" ease="in" />
  <animate  trigger="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryVoltage.valstr}" triggerOn="65024" targetNode="selopacity_Volt"  targetAttr="value" to="0" dur="0ms" ease="in" />
  <animate  trigger="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryCurrent.valstr}" triggerOn="*"  targetNode="selopacity_Amp" targetAttr="value" to="1" dur="0ms" ease="in" />
  <animate  trigger="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryCurrent.valstr}" triggerOn="65024" targetNode="selopacity_Amp"  targetAttr="value" to="0" dur="0ms" ease="in" />
  <dockLayout id="item" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.screenHeight}" depth="-1" clip="false" xmlns="http://www.tat.se/kastor/kml" >
    <dockLayout id="list_item_title" x="0" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.Gearselection.text_heght-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="volt_amp_text" x="0" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listUnselFont}" color="{@csm.itemUnselColor}" dockLayout.halign="left" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="{ItemTitle}" />            
    </dockLayout>    
    <dockLayout id="gear_layout" y="0" x="0" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <image id="battery_image" x="0" dockLayout.halign="left" dockLayout.valign="bottom" opacity="1" src="{@m_MenuModel.Gauges.VoltAmpereMeter.image}"/>
    </dockLayout>
    <!--DockLayout for Voltage Value-->
    <dockLayout id="volt_value" x="0" width="{@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.volt_value_x-@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="volt_value_text" x="0" opacity="{selopacity_Volt*selopacity_Amp}" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listUnselFont}" color="{@csm.itemSelColor}" dockLayout.halign="right" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryVoltage.valstr}" >     
      </text>
    </dockLayout>   
    <!--DockLayout for Voltage Unit-->
    <dockLayout id="volt_unit" x="{@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.volt_unit_x-@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x}" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="volt_unit_text" x="0" opacity="{selopacity_Volt*selopacity_Amp}" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listUnselFont}" color="{@csm.itemSelColor}" dockLayout.halign="left" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="V" >         
      </text>
    </dockLayout>
    <!--DockLayout for Ampere Value-->
    <dockLayout id="ampere_value" x="0" width="{@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.ampere_value_x-@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="ampere_value_text" x="0" opacity="{selopacity_Amp*selopacity_Volt}" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listUnselFont}" color="{@csm.itemSelColor}" dockLayout.halign="right" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="{@m_ds_ML.VIMPBM_BatteryCurrent.valstr}" >   
      </text>
    </dockLayout>
    <!--DockLayout for Ampere Unit-->
    <dockLayout id="ampere_unit" x="{@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.ampere_unit_x-@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x}" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="ampere_unit_text" x="0" opacity="{selopacity_Amp*selopacity_Volt}" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listUnselFont}" color="{@csm.itemSelColor}" dockLayout.halign="left" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="A" >           
      </text>
    </dockLayout>
    <!--DockLayout for containing Data Not Available text-->
    <dockLayout id="no_data_textline" x="{@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x1-@csm.VoltAmpereMeter.List_x}" width="{@csm.screenWidth}" height="{@csm.vmImage_y_gearselection-@csm.pageVisualCP_y}">
      <text id="no_data_text" x="0" opacity="{1-(selopacity_Amp*selopacity_Volt)}" ellipsize="false" font="{@csm.listSelFont}" color="{@csm.itemSelColor}" dockLayout.halign="left" dockLayout.valign="bottom" string="{text1}" >           
      </text>
    </dockLayout>
    <!--<rect id="test_rect1" x="{151-28}" y="0" width="1" height="240" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />
              <rect id="test_rect1" x="{237-28}" y="0" width="1" height="240" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />
              <rect id="test_rect1" x="{160-28}" y="0" width="1" height="240" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />
              <rect id="test_rect1" x="{246-28}" y="0" width="1" height="240" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />
              <rect id="test_rect8" x="0" y="{161-40}" width="320" height="1" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />
              <rect id="test_rect1" x="{109-28}" y="0" width="1" height="240" opacity="1" fill="#00ff00" />-->
  </dockLayout>  
</dockLayout>
```

Comment: If you're trying to make your own templating language, this is probably the wrong way to go.

Comment: hmm, strange... timeit does not show major differences between the version with and without braces. can you give a test case?

Comment: I'm not doing a templating language, I'm trying to postprocess some configuration files which use this format.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I'm using Cygwin's Python 2.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you supply a test case of a string for which the first match is "dog slow"? BTW, though I don't know if that matters to performance, there's an imprecision in the RE -- it matches any single character after the `{@csm` start, not just a dot; maybe a better expression (possibly faster as it doesn't make any dots "optional") could be:

```
r'\{@csm((?:\.\w+)+)\}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly a regex expert, but it might be due to the brace at the end of the match. You might try to match `r"\{@csm.((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.?)+)"` and just check manually whether a closing brace occurs at the end or not.

Comment: Yes, that does give a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give a better example of exactly what's slow. For a reasonably long string containing stuff that does and doesn't match:

```
x="".join(['{@csm.foo.bar-%d}\n{@csm.foo.%dx.baz}\n' % (a,a)
            for a in xrange(10000)])
mymatch=r"\{@csm.((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.?)+)\}"

for y in re.finditer(mymatch,x):
    print y.group(0)
```

works fine, but if you've got a long enough string and you're searching it poorly you could have problems.